# Android LocationServices - Check if location is activated

Tags: android, android-location

I'm implementing a location manager on my app with LocationServices (with google location services) and I'm looking for a way to check if the location is activated on the device system (on Settings). I'm connecting to the location server like this:

```
private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mAppContext)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    createLocationRequest();
}

private void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(SMALLEST_DISPLACEMENT);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}
```

Is there a way to check the availability of the system Location setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this helps

```
LocationManager locateManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
boolean enabled = locateManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
// check if enabled and if not send user to the GPS settings
if (!enabled) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
} // Better solution would be to display a dialog and suggesting to go to the settings
```